# How is `isNaN('blabla');` -> true, a false positive?

Tags: javascript, nan

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

> // This is a false positive and the reason why isNaN is not entirely
>   reliable
>
> isNaN('blabla');   // true: "blabla" is converted to a number.

How is the above a `false positive`? Isn't `blabla` indeed not a number and thus it should be a `true positive` instead. In which the above is not a good example of why `isNaN is not entirely reliable`.

I have looked up for `blabla` to be a number in some number system, didn't come across any.

Comment: Probably in the sense that it isn't testing if the argument is `NaN` directly. The argument is coerced to a Number, becomes `NaN`, then the result of the coercion is checked. I'd think it failing for an illegal argument would be more appropriate.

Comment: Did you read the examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN ?

Comment: @JoshLee yes. The question is not about why the result is true. I understand that, but rather why the documentation says the result true (which is expected) is a false positive.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, since `isNaN(NaN) == true` is indeed true since NaN is Not a Number and thus a true positive.

Comment: It should test for the case if it holds the state `NaN`. If you do `NaN+1` then the result is `NaN`.  But if you do `'blabla'+1` then the result is `blabla1`.

Comment: (Earlier comment deleted) What I meant to add was, can you believe that `typeof NaN == "number"`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is the above a false positive? Isn't blabla indeed not a number
>   and thus it should be a true positive instead.

Because the argument passed to `isNaN()` is *implicitly* converted to a `number` ***type*** (regardless of whether it can be an actual number). I suspect this is because **some strings *can* have a numeric equivalent**.

However, the **[`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)** method is a more specific test and returns the correct result because no conversion takes place - the passed value must not be `NaN` **and** its un-coerced type must be `Number` for it to return `false`.

You can think of these two versions as analogous to `==` and `===`.

```js
console.log(isNaN("BlahBlah"));         // true!
console.log(Number.isNaN("BlahBlah"));  // false ;)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't `blabla` indeed not a number

`NaN` is a number (despite its name being an abbreviation of "not a number"). `isNaN()` checks whether the number you're passing it is `NaN`.

`"blabla"` is not `NaN`. It can't be, because `"blabla"` is not a number at all. That's why `isNaN("blabla")` returning `true` is considered a false positive.

If we're going by its name, `isNaN` should only return `true` if the argument

1. is a number, and
2. has the special value `NaN`.

Instead it implicitly coerces any non-numeric value to a number first, then tests the result. This is how we end up with `isNaN({})` being `true` but `isNaN([])` being `false`.

Of course, if you think of `isNaN(x)` as "*would `x`, when converted to a number, result in `NaN`?*", then this is not a false positive. But that's not what most people expect.

Answer (score 2):

Because `NaN`, specified by `IEEE 754`, is a result of a specific floating point operation. Here is the list

```
 inf  -  inf = NaN
-inf  +  inf = NaN
   0  /  0   = NaN
  -0  /  0   = NaN
   0  / -0   = NaN
  -0  / -0   = NaN
 inf  /  inf = NaN
-inf  /  inf = NaN
 inf  / -inf = NaN
-inf  / -inf = NaN
 inf  *  0   = NaN
 inf  * -0   = NaN
```

therefore checking a value whether it is `NaN` by `isNaN` (according to `IEEE 754`) is the same as asking whether the value is an outcome of any of the above mentioned operations.

`blabla` is not an outcome of any of the above mentioned operation and as such it should not be treated as `NaN`, but it is. (Therefore it is considered a false positive)